# Rescuing multiple exception types, inherited - what is the order of matching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, error-handling

My API controllers sometimes throw Pundit::NotAuthorizedError and I would like to render specific json response with error code `403`. For general errors I would like to render something else, with status `500`.

However the `:render_error` rescue always catches Pundit errors and as a result I get `500`. Why is this happening and what should I do to avoid it?  If I remove `rescue_from StandardError...` altogether, it works fine.  (`ActionController::ParameterMissing` works fine, so I guess it's connected to inheritance, but I would assume that it tries to match exception types in the order they are given in the code).

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::API
  include Pundit

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :render_not_authorized
  rescue_from ActionController::ParameterMissing, with: :render_bad_request
  rescue_from StandardError, with: :render_error

  def  render_not_authorized
     ....
  end

  def  render_error
    ....
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from) where it states:

> Handlers are inherited. They are searched from right to left, from bottom to top, and up the hierarchy. The handler of the first class for which exception.is_a?(klass) holds true is the one invoked, if any.

Note especially the first comment ("Define handlers in order of most generic to most specific") where it states:

> The later the definition of the rescue handler, the higher the priority.
>
> Declaring the Exception catch-all handler last would have the side-effect of precluding any other handlers from running.